# Error with maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, maven-jaxb2-plugin

Im simply trying to duplicate [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/) from Spring's website with my own wsdl files.  FYI I did remove the parent declaration which required me to add versions to the dependencies.  Other then that and filling in wsdl locations its mostly copy paste from the tutorial.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.mynamespace</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-consuming-web-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>com.cisco.tms.sdk.v15</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://x.x.x.x/tms/external/booking/bookingservice.asmx?WSDL</url>
                        </schema>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://x.x.x.x/tms/external/booking/remotesetup/remotesetupservice.asmx?WSDL</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My issues is that I get an error on the line with `<execution>`:

```
Execution default of goal
org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed:
Unable to load the mojo 'generate' in the plugin
'org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1'. A required class
is missing: org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/RawXJC2Mojo
----------------------------------------------------- realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1 strategy =
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy urls[0] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[1] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.13.1.jar
urls[2] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.2.1/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
urls[3] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar
urls[4] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
urls[5] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
urls[6] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb22-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb22-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[7] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
urls[8] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
urls[9] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.jar
Number of foreign imports: 5 import: Entry[import
org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm
ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import
org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core,
parent: null]] import: Entry[import
org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner from realm
ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import
org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm
ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import  from
realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------  (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate:default:generate-sources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of
goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1:generate failed:
Unable to load the mojo 'generate' in the plugin
'org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1'. A required class
is missing: org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/RawXJC2Mojo
----------------------------------------------------- realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1 strategy =
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy urls[0] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[1] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.13.1.jar
urls[2] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.2.1/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
urls[3] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar
urls[4] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
urls[5] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
urls[6] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb22-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb22-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[7] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
urls[8] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
urls[9] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.jar
Number of foreign imports: 5 import: Entry[import
org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm
ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import
org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core,
parent: null]] import: Entry[import
org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner from realm
ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import
org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm
ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import  from
realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at
org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:153)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:331)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1362)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl$11.call(MavenImpl.java:1)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1360)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.build(MojoExecutionBuildParticipant.java:52)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.build(MavenBuilderImpl.java:137)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:172)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$1.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:115)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:105)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:86)
    at
org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.build(MavenBuilder.java:200)
    at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:735)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
    at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
    at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
    at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:360)
    at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:383)
    at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
    at
org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55) Caused
by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: Unable to load
the mojo 'generate' in the plugin
'org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1'. A required class
is missing: org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/RawXJC2Mojo
----------------------------------------------------- realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.13.1 strategy =
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy urls[0] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[1] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core/0.13.1/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.13.1.jar
urls[2] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.2.1/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
urls[3] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar
urls[4] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
urls[5] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
urls[6] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb22-plugin/0.13.1/maven-jaxb22-plugin-0.13.1.jar
urls[7] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
urls[8] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
urls[9] =
file:/C:/Users/dever/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.4/maven-plugin-annotations-3.4.jar
Number of foreign imports: 5 import: Entry[import
org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm
ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import
org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core,
parent: null]] import: Entry[import
org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner from realm
ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import
org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm
ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import  from
realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at
org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:537)
    at
org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
    ... 31 more Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/RawXJC2Mojo  at
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   at
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)   at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)   at
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)   at
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  at
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)   at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:401)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at
org.eclipse.sisu.space.URLClassSpace.loadClass(URLClassSpace.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.NamedClass.load(NamedClass.java:46)   at
org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at
org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at
com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)    at
org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at
org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at
org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
    ... 32 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo  at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at
org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    ... 81 more
```

Comment: stacktrace is too much and unformatted to understand. could you please format it.

Comment: not sure how to format it better, tried a few different options above but none looked better.  Also an FYI, i updated the plugin to the latest 13.1 which gives a different error (updated that as well).

Comment: Spectacular. This is some low-level error, I don't understand how you may be missing the `RawXJC2Mojo`. Try removing plugin+dependencies from you local repository and try again. Maybe something was corrupted on download. If the problem persists, please send me a pull request with a minimal reproducing project under https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin-support/w/wsdl-0

Comment: i have mvn cleaned, as well as fully deleted a few times.  really the project is the pom file and the error will show up even with the bad urls in the scheme.  it red underlines <executions> and when mousing over i get the error posted above.  FYI there were a few other post that i found saying that its caused from eclipse pointing to a jre.  My installed jre's setting shows its pointing to a JDK and i have tried the -vm switch to ensure it was pointing to the right JDK, but none affected the error